# Login using Mysql database username and password

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to make my php scripts protected pages, and so when adding a login i want it to check the username and password inputs against the database username and password and if they match it will allow them to view the protected pages until logout. I've been able to set up the protected page & logout based on a dummy login username and password now i want to connect it to the database users. This is my html & php code. Any help would be appreciated :)

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
 <table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<caption>
Staff Login
</caption>
<tr>
    <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="2"/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="2"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

// Check if username and password are correct


if ($_POST["username"] == 'username' && $_POST["password"] == 'password') {
include 'connection.php'; 
// If correct, we set the session to YES
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["Login"] = "YES";
  echo "You are now logged in.</br></br>";
  echo "<a href='list-contacts.php'>Proceed to contacts...</a>";

}
else {

// If not correct, we set the session to NO
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["Login"] = "NO";
  echo "Incorrect username and / or password.</br></br>";
  echo "<a href='login.html'>Return to login</a>";

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your sql query?

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: What about session hijacking and cross site scripting? Your script doesn't defend you from this sort of attacks.

Look at this tutorial here:
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL 

Its simple and quiet secure

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php session_start();
    include('../db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){

        if(!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])){
            $get_username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_name']);
            $get_password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_password']);
            $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name= '$get_username' AND user_password = '$get_password' ";

            if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
                    header('Location:../admin/index.php');
                }else{
                    header('Location:../index.php?login=wrong');
                }               
            }else{
                header('Location:../index.php?login=error');
            }               
        }else{
            header('Location:../index.php?login=empty');
            }       
    }else{}

?>
```

This is a php 5 mysqli_num_row() function to varifiy username and password from db..

Comment: do never concatenate use prepared statements. mysqli_real_escape_string does not protect you from injection.

Answer (score -2):

1. always assign session at the top of page, before any output is sent to browser.
2. you can check the username and password inputs against the database by the simple my sql query

---

```
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","db_name");
$query=mysqli_query("select from users_table where username='".$_POST['username']."' and password='".$_POST['password']."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==1) { 
    //set session data here
    //redirect user to where you want
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Include your `connection.php` before your 
`if ($_POST["username"] == 'username' && $_POST["password"] == 'password')` condition and then run a select query on your db to fetch username and password like `"select * from tablename where username='$_POST["username"]' and password='$_POST["password"]'"` and then in your if check that the query result is not empty

you can also check this link for mysql-php login system:-

http://www.sourcecodetuts.com/php/27/how-create-login-page-php-and-mysql-session variable